# База данных "Сотрудники школы"

Tags: база-данных, sql

Как организовать таблицу подтипов для сотрудников школы. Сотрудниками могут быть учителя, администрация, тех. персонал. Учителя могут быть и администрацией.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте, чтобы первичный ключ в таблицах учителей, администрации и пр. был одновременно внешним ключом на таблицу сотрудников школы с каскадным удалением. В таблице сотрудников размещайте общие атрибуты, в таблицах подтипов - специальные. Кроме того, таблица сотрудников должна иметь колонку, идентифицирующую подтип.

При получении данных для каждого подтипа возвращайте объединение таблицы подтипа с таблицей сотрудников. При сохранении данных сначала сохраняйте данные в таблицу сотрудников, потом в таблицу подтипа.

Answer (score 0):

Вам понадобятся 3 таблицы:
 1. Сотрудники (id int, fio vch(255));
 2. Подтипы (id int, nazv vsc(255)); -- учитель, администрация, тех. персонал, проч.
 3. Должности (idsotr int, idpd int); -- idsotr это номер из первой таблицы, idpd это номер из второй таблицы.